# Language agnostic style checker?

Tags: coding-style, continuous-integration, static-analysis

Is there a language agnostic style checker?

I'm using some proprietary languages, and I would like to enforce some generic code guidelines for continuous integration. For example:

- file contains a header matching a specific pattern
- use spaces over tabs
- indentation should be 2 spaces
- file length should be < 5000 lines
- file names should follow a specific pattern

Comment: I think you are really unlikely to find a language-agnostic tool for this, since style is often stated in terms of syntax.   What you need are tools that can be configured for your proprietary language.  (See my bio if you are interested in such tools).

Comment: I've been looking for a similar application without much success. I started a project with the hope that others find it easy to expand and figure this is an appropriate place to mention it. https://github.com/erichschroeter/sc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a tool dealing with language-agnostic checks specifically. The things you can check without knowing the language are limited.

But: Checkstyle has a small number of language-agnostic checks which all derive from [`AbstractFileSetCheck`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/AbstractFileSetCheck.html):

- AbstractHeaderCheck (!)
- FileLengthCheck (!)
- FileTabCharacterCheck (!)
- <del>JavadocPackageCheck</del>
- NewlineAtEndOfFileCheck
- RegexpMultilineCheck
- RegexpSinglelineCheck
- StrictDuplicateCodeCheck
- TranslationCheck

Indentation is very hard to do right if you don't know the language, but some of the use cases you list should be covered (the top three). You can also [add your own language-agnostic checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html#Writing_FileSetChecks).
In addition to that, the two checks that simply match regular expressions are very powerful if you are good at building regexes.